# Como comparar una contraseña que se guarda en WordPress con la contraseña que ingresa el usuario?

Tags: php, wordpress, webservice, hash, md5

En mi base de datos en WordPress las contraseñas se guardan de la siguiente forma: $P$BhbEVMLV6onULEfYLG3dsF5xuv9t9j0

Lo que no he logrado hacer es comparar esa contraseña contra la que ingresa el usuario en un EditText, he intentando usar la funcion de **password_verify()**
pero no me funciona, este es el codigo que tengo para hacer una prueba pero no se que estoy haciendo mal al momento de hacer la validacion:

```
if(password_verify($password, '$P$BhbEVMLV6onULEfYLG3dsF5xuv9t9j0')){
            echo "Las contraseñas son correctas";
        }else{
            echo "No funciona la validacion";
        }
```

Hasta donde he investigado WordPress usa esto para las contraseñas:

```
$wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);  
$pass = $wp_hasher->HashPassword($_POST['password']);
```

Pero ya he intentado convirtiendo la contraseña que ingresa el usuario al mismo formato de WordPress pero tampoco me resulta la validacion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una búsqueda rápida nos lleva a [How to manage a PHP application's users and passwords](https://www.openwall.com/articles/PHP-Users-Passwords). Ahí se nos indica, entre otras muchas cosas, que para verificar es:

```
if( $hwp_hasher->CheckPassword( $password, '$P$BhbEVMLV6onULEfYLG3dsF5xuv9t9j0' ) ) {
  echo 'Autentificación correcta !';
} else {
  echo 'Error de autentificación';
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias,me funciono a la perfeccion

Answer (score 0):

para poder hacer un login no tenes que volver a hashear la contraseña

tenes que usar

```
password_verify($contraseñaQueIngreso, $ContraseñaDeLaBd);
```

eso va a retornar true si el password se verifico y es correcto

el primer parametro es una contraseña sin hashear, el segundo es contra el que queres comparar que tiene que estar hasheado.

Comment: De echo ya lo intente como mencionas pero sigue validando que las contraseñas no son iguales